# Is there any difference betweeen: onClick="this.href= inside an <a> tag versus a js redirect using "window.location.href"?

Tags: javascript

Basically the title says it all but I am running a customer aff-program on my shopping site and it seems one of my aff's gets a "abnormal"  results although I'm not sure. This made me thinking if there is any differences (on my side) referral wise etc. if the aff in question is using js redirect instead of my aff-link structure?

My structure:

```html
<a href="http://www.myshop.com" onClick="this.href='http://www.myshop.com/aff.php?affcode=0000'" />LINK</a>
```

Suspected structure:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="http://www.myshop.com/aff.php?affcode=0000";</script>
```

or something similar, I am not a coder/programmer as you notice, perhaps the suspected code is wrong but you get the point with the js redirect.

Will these two give different output/referral/stat (on my side) or same?

Comment: `<a href="http://www.myshop.com/aff.php?affcode=0000"" />LINK</a>` is all you need, sup with the javascript.

Comment: agreed. What is the need to have JavaScript enabled redirection?

Comment: Is the javascript there to trick the user when he hovers over the link ?

Comment: ok, but my aff-program used outputs it like explained above (<a href="http://www.myshop.com" onClick="this.href='http://www.myshop.com/aff.php?affcode=0000'" />LINK</a>) without the () and since the files (php) are protected (I just see some strange/derange code when opening up a file) I cannot change this.

Comment: "agreed. What is the need to have JavaScript enabled..?"
"Is the javascript there to trick the user when he..?"

Like mentioned I cannot change my aff-link to my affiliates since it is protected so I have to use the structure mentioned above. What I was wondering is WOULD I notice any difference, as far as referrer etc. is concerned, if an affiliate is using the above mentioned "suspected structure" will the referrer or click be different or the same as "my structure" also mentioned above? I am suspicious about one of the aff-members thats why I am asking, hope you understand what I mean.....

Comment: there shouldn't be any functional/http request differences. The browser MAY store the history slightly differently, but that should have no effect on the page or it's rendering, and should only affect JavaScript if you're accessing the history object.

Comment: @The E Thanks for your reply. This means I cannot know if this particular aff-member is fooling me by using second ("suspected structure") or not, right :( ?

Comment: without looking at their code, I would say no, you can't